# React-native get error "Network request failed"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I'm new to the react native, and I'm trying to get data from  API, but I got tired and could not find a solution.

I'm used :

1. . net core 6
2. visual code
3. expo  to run simulator IOS

**- my react App**

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import Home from "./screens/Home";

export default function App() {
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState("Loading..");
  const getWeather = async () => {
    var res = await fetch("https://192.168.1.205:5001/WeatherForecast", {
      method: "GET",
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        alert("Succ");
        // Handle response here
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        alert(error);
      });
  };

  // return <Home />
  getWeather();
  return (
    <View>
      <Text></Text>
      <Text style={{ paddingTop: 50, marginLeft: 30 }}>{weather}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

**- Controller**

```
  using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    
    namespace RestaurantAPI.Controllers
    {
        [ApiController]
        [Route("[controller]")]
        public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
        {
            private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
            {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };
    
            private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;
    
            public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
            {
                _logger = logger;
            }
    
            [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
            public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
            {
                return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
                {
                    Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                    TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                    Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
                })
                .ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

**- Prgoram.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var CorsPolicy = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>

{

    options.AddPolicy(name: CorsPolicy,

                      b =>

                      {

                          b.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin();

                      });

});
builder.WebHost.UseKestrel();
builder.WebHost.UseUrls("http://localhost:5001", "https://192.168.1.205:5001");
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

//app.UseHttpsRedirection(); by waleed
app.UseCors(CorsPolicy);
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

**- Postman Request**

when call this url in postman it get data

[image]

when call api from ReactNative in visual code get this error:"**Network request failed**"

[image]

Note :

- used the localhost url API
- used the IP network to hit server side
- create new port ("5001")
- add CorsPolicy in program.cs

but get same error; please can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

Fetch fails on Android with that error if you don’t set a Content-type header. Try adding one to your fetch request.

```
headers: {
  'Content-type': 'application/json'
}
```

Comment: `const getWeather = async () => {
    var res = await fetch("https://192.168.1.205:5001/WeatherForecast", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        alert("Succ");
        // Handle response here
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        alert(error);
      });
  };`

I added the header but  the same problem "Network request field"

@cat

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately that's a non-descript error message, that can be nearly anything. 
 What device are you running RN on?  Since this is a GET, can you put the URL (https://192.168.1.205:5001/WeatherForecast) in the device's browser and see if you get the response back?  If it times out, look for a firewall issue.

I'm wondering if you're running Postman on the machine running the API server, but testing RN on a separate device that's getting blocked by a firewall.  If that's the case but it works in the browser, then you're looking at something with RN/fetch, specifically.

Comment: after put the url in browser get this message 

`Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from 192.168.1.205 (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards).

NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`

then after press "Proceed to 192.168.1.205 (unsafe)" in browser the browser get data.

Comment: There you go - that looks like actual problem.  You've got a certificate error and that's probably why your phone is refusing to fetch.  You can switch to http, but you'll need to read and follow links from the big yellow box on this documentation page: https://reactnative.dev/docs/network .  Or you could get a certificate set up on your server, but that's beyond the scope of what I can help you with.

Answer (score 0):

Run your backend app using your Computer IP address e.g on django its `Python manage.py runserver 191.223.233.222:8000` then use "http://191.223.233.222:8000" on your react native domain.

also on your app.json file under iOS add `"ios": { "supportsTablet": true, "infoPlist": { "NSAppTransportSecurity" : { "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads" : true } } },`
to give your permissions to allow http requests

Answer (score 0):

While working on Android app development, I encountered similar error when trying to fetch content from a Django-hosted API to my React Native app. Fortunately, I found a solution that resolved the issue. Here are the steps that worked for me:

1. Add Your IP to ALLOWED_HOSTS in settings.py: In your Django project’s settings.py file, locate the ALLOWED_HOSTS list. Add your local IP address (you can find it using ipconfig) to the list. For example:

   `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['IP.IP.IP.IP', '0.0.0.0', '192.0.0.1', 'yourIP']`
2. Specify the IP and Port When Running the Server: When starting the Django development server (e.g., using python3 manage.py runserver newIP:port), provide the IP address you added in step 1. For instance:

   `python3 manage.py runserver 192.0.0.1:8000`

If you’re using an IDE like PyCharm, you can configure these parameters in the run/debug configurations, and they will be automatically applied.

3. Update the Fetch URL in Your React Native App: Make sure to update the API endpoint in your React Native code to use the new IP and port. For example:

```
fetch('http://newIP:8000/app/data')
  .then(/* handle response */)
  .catch(/* handle error */);
```

In summary, Remember to use your local IP address for hosting during development and host it on that.